# Need To Move Featured Picture Over

Tags: html, blogger

I added a border to my posts and once I did so, it made the picture and text on the homepage (see below) smush together. I would like to adjust the margins so that the Gucci belt picture and text are not touching.

https://www.500daysofstyle.com/
[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T6XCV.jpg)

I'm not sure what to search in my HTML to adjust that.

Please help!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In blog theme editor find `.page .widget.FeaturedPost .thumb.hero-thumb`, and add a right margin within block:

```css
.page .widget.FeaturedPost .thumb.hero-thumb {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  width: 412.5px;
  margin-right: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Omg, I ended up needing to change my width from 2 to 2.5.

.page .widget.FeaturedPost .thumb.hero-thumb{
height:auto;
min-height:300px;
width:$(content.width / 2.5 - 10px)
}

But you absolutely pointed me in the right direction. 

Thank you so much!!!